# Configure multiple interfaces with different hostnames using DHCP and DNS

Tags: ubuntu, networking, freebsd, dns, dhcp

I have a machine running Ubuntu 12.04 Server with two interfaces connected (eth0, eth1) to the network. Our network is set up so that a FreeBSD based DHCP server hands out leases and registers the client supplied host names with a DNS server on the same network.

The two interfaces need to have different host names to register both on DNS. In /etc/network/interfaces I have added the hostname for eth1:

```
# The primary network interface (hostname: host0)
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

# Secondary interface 
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
  hostname host1
```

The dhcp client config looks something like this:

```
    option rfc3442-classless-static-routes code 121 = array of unsigned integer 8;

    send host-name "<hostname>";
    request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
            domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
            netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
            rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers,
            dhcp6.domain-search, dhcp6.fqdn,
            dhcp6.name-servers, dhcp6.sntp-servers;
```

The leases obtained look like this:

```
# /var/run/resolvconf/interface/eth0.dhclient
lease {
  interface "eth0";
  fixed-address 192.168.28.249;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option routers 192.168.28.30;
  option dhcp-lease-time 129600;
  option dhcp-message-type 5;
  option domain-name-servers 192.168.28.1,192.168.24.58;
  option dhcp-server-identifier 192.168.28.1;
  option ntp-servers 192.168.28.1,192.168.58.43,192.168.24.58;
  option broadcast-address 192.168.28.255;
  option domain-name "some.org";
  renew 4 2014/02/20 01:00:39;
  rebind 4 2014/02/20 15:31:19;
  expire 4 2014/02/20 20:01:19;
}

# /var/run/resolvconf/interface/eth1.dhclient
lease {
  interface "eth1";
  fixed-address 192.168.19.69;
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option routers 192.168.19.30;
  option dhcp-lease-time 129600;
  option dhcp-message-type 5;
  option domain-name-servers 192.168.28.1,192.168.24.58;
  option dhcp-server-identifier 192.168.28.1;
  option ntp-servers 192.168.28.1,192.168.58.43,192.168.24.58;
  option broadcast-address 192.168.19.255;
  option domain-name "some.org";
  renew 3 2014/02/19 21:56:46;
  rebind 4 2014/02/20 15:30:42;
  expire 4 2014/02/20 20:00:42;
}
```

I do not have control over the FreeBSD DHCP server, but have been told the leases were recorded as:

```
#####################
lease 192.168.28.249 {
starts 5 2014/02/14 03:24:14;
ends 6 2014/02/15 15:24:14;
cltt 5 2014/02/14 03:24:14;
binding state active;
next binding state free;
hardware ethernet 00:01:02:03:04:12;
set ddns-rev-name = "249.28.168.192.in-addr.arpa.";
set ddns-fwd-name = "host0.dhcp.some.org";
client-hostname "host0";
on expiry or release {
switch (ns-update (delete (1, 12, ddns-rev-name, null))) {
case 0:
unset ddns-rev-name ;
break;
}
switch (ns-update (delete (1, 1, ddns-fwd-name, leased-address))) {
case 0:
unset ddns-fwd-name ;
break;
}
on expiry or release;
}
}
lease 192.168.19.69 {
starts 4 2014/02/13 14:40:47;
ends 6 2014/02/15 02:40:47;
cltt 4 2014/02/13 14:40:47;
binding state active;
next binding state free;
hardware ethernet 00:01:02:03:04:14;
client-hostname "host0";
}

#####################
```

In both leases on the server side the client-hostname has the value "host0". Note that the leases were handed out on two different subnets: 192.168.28.0 and 192.168.19.0.

Is my /etc/network/interfaces configuration all that is needed for sending the secondary interface's hostname to the DHCP server? If so, what else should I check on the client side to debug?

(IP addresses and MAC addresses were modified to hide real values)

Comment: have you disable the `network-manager` ? becasue if you run ubuntu with this configuration and the network manager it will never work.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified this is a server, I don't think Ubuntu Server includes the NetworkManager? (Question updated)

Comment: well if you do not install gnome nor unity no `network-manager` is not installed.

Comment: Confirmed. Ubuntu Server 12.04 with no desktop manager.

Comment: I might be wrong but are you sure your DHCP is sending a hostname to ach DHCP client because usually hosname comes from DNS, you can configure I remember a DHCP to attribute a ip to a DNS entry each time DHCP lease is given but it's a DHCP and DNS issue in this case becasue client are still client... I'm not sure...

Comment: I am not sure of the implementation, but the client tells the DHCP server what the client-hostname is, the DHCP server passes that info to the DNS so that other computers can resolve an ip address for the client's hostname.

Comment: It is a type of dynamic DNS setup on the organizational network.

Comment: You can add virtual network interfaces to a physical interface, there is no need for two separate network cards. They will only interfere with each other.

Comment: @vonbrand: Please put this in an answer, I would like to pursue this.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not 100% sure if what you want is possible purely by setting options in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

*In theory*, it's possible by editing `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`. Try adding a stanza like:

```
interface "eth0" {
    send host-name "host0";
}

interface "eth1" {
    send host-name "host1";
}
```

Make sure any other host-name options in that file are commented out and remove the hostname you specified in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: Worked like a charm on Raspberry Pi 2 running Debian!!
http://www.gsp.com/cgi-bin/man.cgi?topic=dhclient.conf#8 has an example for the same as well.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux you can add virtual interfaces to physical ones, and configure and manage them separately (for some long forgotten twisted reason we had our workstations living in two different IP networks running on the same cable for a while). So you really don't need two Ethernet cards, they will probably only interfere with each other.

I don't know if DHCP is up to configuring virtual interfaces. I'd guess not, it's mission is to assign network parameters, and probably covers only the common cases.

Comment: But if I set up the virtual interfaces manually they should be able to each get their own IP addresses hopefully while informing the DHCP server of their unique hostnames? I am not sure how this is different from having two physical interfaces. Its a rack mount server that comes with 2 ethernet ports by default.

Comment: If two physical network cards are "interfering" with each other, something is severely broken on that system.

Comment: This answer deserves an updoot as it is actually possible to use dhcp with virtual interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I removed isc-dhcp-client and switched dhcpcd and the network/interfaces hostname now works.

Comment: So, if you have two different interfaces working, with two different hostnames, what do you get when you type 'hostname<cr>' at the command line? Is it even related ?

Comment: Not relevant. What a system thinks it's name is and what names resolve externally to the interface addresses can be different.

Comment: Interesting, so how does the mail server determine what to add after @  ? Is it related to either one of them?

Comment: @Dennis it uses system hostname, or in case of postfix, its own config parameter `mailname`

Comment: @EricWoodruff  Would you mind sharing the `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` and `/etc/network/interfaces` content?